# Stop fragments calling onCreateOptionsMenu

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-spinner

I have an app where users can switch between a list fragment and a map fragment using a switch within the single activity. I am having issues where when a users switches the fragment view, onCreateOptionsMenu.

This has become an issues as I have a spinner in the actionbar that allows users to filter data to a filter of there choice and it is being reset if a user decides to switch view.

IE. filtering by "English Earthquakes" on the list view shows the desired result but switching to the map view resets because the map fragment calls onCreateOptionsMenu again.

[image: showing the ability to switch fragment dynamically]

onCreateOptionsMenu method in MainActivity

```
    //Inflating Menue
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu,menu);


    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.spinner);
    spinner = (Spinner) item.getActionView();

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.action_share,  getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Planets)){
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            //Explicitly used to turn spinner into an icon
            LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
            View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.action_share, parent, false);

            return view;
        }
    };

    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    spinner.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search));

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            String selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            ChangeView(selectedItem);
        } // to close the onItemSelected
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
        {

        }
    });

    return true;
```

Fragment switching code within onCreate in MainActivity

```
        onOffSwitch = (Switch)  findViewById(R.id.switchy);
    onOffSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked == true){
                //Changes to the map Fragment
                ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.framlayoutMap, new NonListfragment());
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
            }
            else
            {
                //Changes to the list fragment
                ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.framlayoutMap, new EQListFragment ());
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
            }
        }
    });

    //Used to set it so the starting of the application does not have blank fragment
    ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.framlayoutMap, new EQListFragment ());
    ft.commit();
```

onCreate in List Fragment

```
public class EQListFragment extends ListFragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    setHasOptionsMenu(false);
}
```

onCreate in the map fragment does not have sethasOptionsMenu set to false as it extends FragmentActivity

The matter is how to stop a fragment calling onCreateOptionsMenu in the parent activity when its loaded. It seems this also happens when the device is roated.

Comment: Have you figured this out yet?